# Trying to play with apache virtual hosts, getting access forbidden errors

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, virtualhost, windows-vista, http-status-code-403

I'm just messing around with virtual hosts on my XAMPP + Apache install on Windows to make it work so that `http://disko.local` redirects to a folder in my PC where the project's files are stored.
I've added the following lines to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       disko.local
::1             localhost
```

And then proceeded to edit the file `X:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf` to add these lines at the bottom of the file (do they have to be in any special place?):

```
# My custom vhosts
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
   DocumentRoot "X:\Work\Web Development\Projects\disko\serverroot"
   ServerName disko.local
</VirtualHost>
```

With a fast search through the file I determined that that was the only vhost present in the file.

Then I restarted Apache, opened my browser and tried to load the page `http://disko.local/artists.html`. This is the error that appeared:

> **Access forbidden!**
>
> You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either
>   read-protected or not readable by the server.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> **Error 403**
>
> disko.local 10/22/11 16:06:58 Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.21
>   OpenSSL/1.0.0e PHP/5.3.8 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1

I tried adding a `.htaccess` file containing the string `allow from all` but that was of no help.

Here's what the error.log file says:

```
[Sat Oct 22 16:06:58 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: X:/Work/Web Development/Projects/disko/serverroot/artists.html
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to add anything to the VHost definition? Thanks in advance.

**P.S.:** Here's the version of Apache, in case it's needed:

```
X:\xampp\apache\bin>httpd.exe -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.21 (Win32)
Server built:   Sep 10 2011 11:34:11
```

Answer (score 1):

Your missing the directory permissions. Inside the virtualhost block place...

```
<Directory "X:\Work\Web Development\Projects\disko\serverroot">
  order allow,deny
  allow from all
</Directory>
```

Make changes. Restart Apache.

Comment: I'm still getting a 403. The code is now:

http://pastebin.com/z0YTatJQ

Comment: Also, the server is running from a different disk than apache.

Comment: Oh, should I put that inside the VirtualHost tags?

Comment: Nope, still not working.